# jQuery Drag & Drop automatically open link inside drag element

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

I'm making a drag and drop shopping cart using jQuery and FoxyCart, the drag and drop work but I don't know how to automatically open a link (inside the drag element) once item is dropped into the cart.

Basically I have a list `<ul>` with `<li class="drag">` and inside I have `<a href="..."><img src=".."  alt="thumbnail"/></a>` and `<a href="..." class="addtocart">Add to cart</a>`. The link for adding to cart is hidden using css, but I need it such that when I drop an item in the shopping cart, it will open this hidden link (because the link opens a modal box and add the item in the real shopping cart provided by FoxyCart). The problem for me is that I don't know jquery that well and I don't know how filter the link from the rest and then open it.

Comment: Are you using jQuery UI draggable/droppable?

Comment: Nobody can answer? ..at least tell me whether it's possibile or not, because I'm going crazy trying to understand the documentation of jQuery and I really don't know where and what I need to look for :)

Comment: Man, look at the cobwebs in here.

Comment: Hey, Raf, if you see an answer that strikes your fancy, let me know and I'll select that as correct.

Answer (score 5):

If your list looks like this:

```
<ul>
    <li class="drag">
        <a href="whatever" class="link-to-open">this link will be opened when dropped</a>
    </li>
    <li class="drag">
        <a href="whatever" class="link-to-open">this link will be opened when dropped</a>
    </li> 
</ul>
```

In your shopping cart Droppable object:

```
$('#shopping-cart').droppable({
    drop: function(e,ui) {
        $(ui.draggable).find('.link-to-open').click()
    }
});
```

Comment: `$(ui.draggable).find('.link-to-open').click()`

Comment: I think, $(ui.draggable).find('.link-to-open').trigger("click") instead of click(), is more in place (seems more right;))

Comment: I originally had `trigger('click')` and I do normally use that, but for the sake of simplicity, i changed it to click.

Answer (score 4):

Here is your code:

```
$('.drag').draggable({
                revert: "invalid",
                helper: "clone"
            });
$('.cart').droppable({
    accept: ".drag",
    drop: function(event, ui){       
        window.location=$(ui.draggable).find("a.addtocart").attr("href");
    }
});
```

Here is the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sPbmM/4/)

Answer (score 1):

On the elements you want to drag, such as a DIV which has  you thumbnail and item name etc. you need to give it a class like `shoppingcartItem` (or what ever else you have chosen)

The jQuery for the item that you drag will then be

```
$('.shoppingcartItem').draggable({ 
    /* Don't forget, you can change this class name to match what you have */
    revert: "invalid",
    helper: "clone"
});
```

Then, you need to have you cart area that you drop items onto with a class or ID along the lines of "shoppingCart", I think ID make more sense in this case, as you would only have one cart and this cart will be used only as a cart.

```
$('#shoppingCart').droppable({
    accept: ".shoppingcartItem", /* this needs to match up with what you used */
    drop: function(event, ui){       
        window.location=$(ui.draggable).find("a.postAddToCart").attr("href");
    }
});
```

Now, to explain the 'function' here, this is searching for an `<a>` tag, of link tag, which has a class `postAddToCart` and then call the link tag. Though this will open the link in the same window. I am not too sure if this is what you want, if not perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827637/jquery-open-link-in-new-window) will help you out