# How can I open a link in a new window?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a click handler for a specific link, inside that I want to do something similar to the following:

```
window.location = url
```

I need this to actually open the url in a new window though, how do I do this?

Answer (score 209, accepted):

You can like:

```
window.open('url', 'window name', 'window settings')
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('a#link_id').click(function(){
  window.open('url', 'window name', 'window settings');
  return false;
});
```

You could also set the `target` to `_blank` actually.

Comment: but this jquery code will not navigate to the target automatically

Comment: _blank is the default target, so using window.open(url) should suffice

Comment: Not sure will help and not exactly same issue but I was searching for same solution to **download** a file (not from a link but a button) and on Chrome the window didn't open and no download until I simply change to window.location = 'url' which doesn't change location but download the file...

Comment: window.open(url) is fine :)

Answer (score 34):

Here's how to force the target inside a click handler:

```
$('a#link_id').click(function() {
    $(this).attr('target', '_blank');
});
```

Comment: No need of using jQuery selector in the click handler so line `$(this).attr('target', '_blank');`  could be changed to `this.target = "_blank";` Also, if the anchor links on the page can be modified to have `rel="external"` attributes then you could create a global click handler for the page with the jQuery selector `a[rel="external"]` rather than having a click handler per link selected with `a#link_id`

Answer (score 16):

you will need to use  `window.open(url);`

references:
http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/linking/linking_famsupp_120.html
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Comment: Yikes!  Don't use or link to w3schools, it's NOT associated with the W3C.  Use MDN instead: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open

Comment: w3schools is good (ignore the 'few' w3c trolls)... will continue to be AN authoritative source...even w3c now are backing it again ;-)

Answer (score 5):

You can also use the jquery prop() method for this.

```
$(function(){
  $('yourselector').prop('target', '_blank');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I just found an interesting solution to this issue. I was creating spans which contain information based on the return from a web service. I thought about trying to put a link around the span so that if I clicked on it, the "a" would capture the click.

But I was trying to capture the click with the span... so I thought why not do this when I created the span.

```
var span = $('<span id="something" data-href="'+url+'" />');
```

I then bound a click handler to the span which created a link based on the 'data-href' attribute:

```
span.click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var href = $(this).attr('data-href');
    var link = $('<a href="http://' + href + '" />');
    link.attr('target', '_blank');
    window.open(link.attr('href'));
});
```

This successfully allowed me to click on a span and open a new window with a proper url.

Answer (score 1):

this solution also considered the case that url is empty and disabled(gray) the empty link.

```js
$(function() {
  changeAnchor();
});

function changeAnchor() {
  $("a[name$='aWebsiteUrl']").each(function() { // you can write your selector here
    $(this).css("background", "none");
    $(this).css("font-weight", "normal");

    var url = $(this).attr('href').trim();
    if (url == " " || url == "") { //disable empty link
      $(this).attr("class", "disabled");
      $(this).attr("href", "javascript:void(0)");
    } else {
      $(this).attr("target", "_blank");// HERE set the non-empty links, open in new window
    }
  });
}
```

```css
a.disabled {
  text-decoration: none;
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: default;
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a name="aWebsiteUrl" href="http://www.baidu.com" class='#'>[website]</a>
<a name="aWebsiteUrl" href=" " class='#'>[website]</a>
<a name="aWebsiteUrl" href="http://www.alibaba.com" class='#'>[website]</a>
<a name="aWebsiteUrl" href="http://www.qq.com" class='#'>[website]</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft IE does not support a name as second argument.

```
window.open('url', 'window name', 'window settings');
```

Problem is `window name`. This will work:

```
window.open('url', '', 'window settings')
```

Microsoft only allows the following arguments, If using that argument at all:

- _blank
- _media
- _parent
- _search
- _self
- _top

[Check this Microsoft site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536651%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: -1: Your licence-violating copy/paste from http://stackoverflow.com/a/1462500/560648 notwithstanding, that's not true. [The argument _is_ supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534659%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It just can't contain spaces or dashes or other punctuation. Read other answers and comments on that question.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware if you want to **execute AJAX requests** inside the event handler function for the click event. For some reason Chrome (and maybe other browsers) will not open a new tab/window.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a very nice fix but it works:

CSS:

```
.new-tab-opener
{
    display: none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<a data-href="http://www.google.com/" href="javascript:">Click here</a>
<form class="new-tab-opener" method="get" target="_blank"></form>
```

Javascript:

```
$('a').on('click', function (e) {    
    var f = $('.new-tab-opener');
    f.attr('action', $(this).attr('data-href'));
    f.submit();
});
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/7eRLb/

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with `<a href="myurl.html" target="_blank">My Link</a>`? No Javascript needed...